# Prove identity.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $\xi >0$ and $\beta \in {\mathcal R}$. Define $x := x(\xi)$ as one of the roots of a quadratic equation:
\begin{equation}
\xi^{2 \beta} x^2 - x + 1 =0
\end{equation}
The question is to prove the following identity:

\begin{equation}
(-2\beta) \frac{\xi^{-2 \beta-1}}{(x - \xi^{-2 \beta})^2} + x \frac{\beta \xi^{2 \beta-1}}{1-2 x \xi^{2 \beta}} \left(1 - \frac{\xi^{-2 \beta}(3 x - \xi^{-2 \beta})}{x(x-\xi^{-2\beta})^2}\right) = 0
\end{equation}

Indeed, if you type the above into Mathematica and apply FullSimplify[] to it we get zero. How can we prove it analytically?

Answer (score 0):

Let us first reduce both terms to the common denominator. We have:
\begin{equation}
\frac{-2 \beta \xi^{-1+2 \beta}}{(-1+x \xi^{2 \beta})^2} + \frac{\beta \xi^{2 \beta-1} \left(1 + x - 3 x \xi^{2 \beta} - 2 x^2 \xi^{2 \beta} + x^3 \xi^{4 \beta}\right)}{(-1+x \xi^{2 \beta})^2(1 - 2 x \xi^{2 \beta})}
\end{equation}
Now we factor out the common terms.
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\beta \xi^{-1+2 \beta}}{(-1+x \xi^{2 \beta})^2} \left(-2  + 
\frac{\left(1 + x - 3 x \xi^{2 \beta} - 2 x^2 \xi^{2 \beta} + x^3 \xi^{4 \beta}\right)}{(1 - 2 x \xi^{2 \beta})}
\right) = \\
\frac{\beta \xi^{-1+2 \beta}}{(-1+x \xi^{2 \beta})^2}
\left(\frac{x^3 \xi^{4 \beta} - 2 x^2 \xi^{2 \beta} + x(1+\xi^{2\beta}) - 1}{1 - 2 x \xi^{2 \beta}}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
Now, a miracle appears!;-) It turns out that the third order polynomial in the numerator factorizes very nicely:
\begin{equation}
x^3 \xi^{4 \beta} - 2 x^2 \xi^{2 \beta} + x(1+\xi^{2\beta}) - 1 = (-1 + x \xi^{2 \beta}) (1 - x + x^2 \xi^{2 \beta})
\end{equation}
Since the last factor on the right-hand side is, from the definition of x, identicaly equal to zero the whole expression is also equal to zero. The only question remains, how can I find out in the first place that the third order polynomial factorizes so nicely?